# How to inspect any android app's HTTP/HTTPS request using Requestly.io?

Tags: proxy, certificates, https

Requestly.io currently allows to intersect the HTTP and HTTPS packets if requests are made from google chrome as the SSL certificates can not be installed for "VPN and App".

How to inspect any android app's HTTP/HTTPS request using Requestly.io if the phone is running Android T (13)?

Comment: Android apps by default do not trust user CA certificates so it doesn't matter which proxy you use you can not intercept SSL/TLS respectively https connections unless the phone is rooted or you modify the app to accept user CA certificates. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/62731432/150978

Comment: I have seen examples from Brup suit that allows that

Comment: Those examples were written for a much older Android version. They don't work for recent Android versions and recent Android apps from Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

To Intercept and modify HTTPs Requests from Chrome, Firefox & Edge browsers, you can use the native browser extensions. You can install them here

- [Chrome Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-open-source-htt/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa)
- [Edge Store](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/requestly-open-source-ht/ehghoapnlpepjmfbgaomdiilchcjemak)
- [For Firefox](https://requestly.io/downloads/firefox/)

To Intercept and modify HTTPs Requests from Mobile Apps, Mobile browsers, or Desktop Apps like Terminal, Slack, etc, you can use the Desktop App.

- [Desktop App Download for Mac, Windows & Linux](https://requestly.io/desktop/)

Once you download the desktop app, Setting up Interception is a two-step process

1. Donwload and Install the SSL certificate generated by the Requestly Desktop app on your Android device
2. Configuring Proxy Settings so that traffic can be passed through the Requestly desktop app installed on your device

To set up interception traffic from Android apps, you can refer to the following

- https://developers.requestly.io/setup/android-apps/
- https://requestly.io/blog/modify-http-traffic-from-android-apps/

Hope it helps!

Comment: The question is about Android apps and the linked instructions can only work for apps that allow user CAs (which means it works with next to no app except Chrome).